# Login form not redirecting after login

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a login form but when it logins successfuly it doesn't redirect to the page i want. I want it to redirect to a html page i got name PF1.1.html but in the example i give the address to google but it still doesn't work. The javascript is working all of it except the redirect part and i don't know why i trie to use replace instead of href but still not working

```js
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if ( username == "teste" && password == "teste"){
alert ("Login successfully");
window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/webhp?ie=UTF-8&rct=j"; // Redirecting to other page.
return false;
}
else{
attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
if( attempt == 0){
document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
return false;
}
}
}
```

```css
/*******************************************LOGIN********************************/
html, body {
  width: 3779.527559055px;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #444;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 background-color: #111;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

zoom{
zoom: 25%;
}
/*******************************************SHUTDOWN BUTTON********************************/
#btn1{
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button img{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
/*********************************************LOGIN***************************************/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide);

::-moz-selection {
    background: #cc0000;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #cc0000;
    text-shadow: none;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.background-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
  outline: none;
}

form {
  background: #111;
  border-radius: .4em;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  height: 1000px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1500px;
}

form:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #111111, #444444, #b6b6b8, #444444, #2F2F2F, #272727);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

form:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  left: 34%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  width: 8px;
}

.inset {
  border-top: 1px solid #19191a;
  padding: 20px;
}

form h1 {
  font-family: 'Audiowide';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 200px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

form h1 {
  color: #FFbb00;
  font-family: Audiowide;
  font-weight: normal;
}

form h1.poweron {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  animation: flicker 1s ease-in-out 1 alternate, neon 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
}

form h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 180px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 138px;
  transform-style: flat;
  transform: skew(20deg);

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%, hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0.2)), color-stop(100%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#42ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);

}

input[type=username], input[type=password] {
  background: linear-gradient(#1f2124,#27292c);
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=username]:disabled, input[type=password]:disabled {
 color: #999;
}


.p-container {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.p-container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.p-container span {
  color: #0d93ff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #fb0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color: #873C00;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.denied {
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
  background: #EE0000 !important;
}

input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=submit]:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

input[type=text]:hover:not([disabled]), 
input[type=text]:focus, 
input[type=password]:hover:not([disabled]), 
input[type=password]:focus, 
label:hover ~ input[type=text], 
label:hover ~ input[type=password] {
  background: #27292c;
}


@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  to {
      text-shadow: 
      0 0 3px #fff,
      0 0 7px  #fff,
      0 0 13px  #fff,
      0 0 17px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 33px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 38px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 48px #B6FF00,
      0 0 63px #B6FF00;
    }
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  2% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  8% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  10% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  20% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  22% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  24% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  28% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  32% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  34% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  36% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  42% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  100% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Desk+ - Grupo 36</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PF1.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="Locked Screen">
    <div id="Login">
            <div class="background-wrap">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <form id="accesspanel">
                    <h1 id="litheader">Desk+</h1>
                    <div class="inset">
                      <p>
                        <input id="username" type="username" size="64" maxLength="64"
                        placeholder=Username(teste)>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password(teste)" required>
                      </p>
                      <div style="text-align: center;">
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-container">
                      <input onclick="validate()" type="submit" id="go" value="Login">
                    </p>
                  </form>
    </div>

    <datalist id="users">
        <option value="teste">
      </datalist>

    <div id="Logout">
    <!---<a href="logout.php" id="LogoutAction"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/exit.png"></a>--->
    <button type="submit" id="btn1"><img src= "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/exit.png"/></button>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

By the way put it in fullscreen and reduce the zoom to 25%

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://appendto.com/2016/04/javascript-redirect-how-to-redirect-a-web-page-with-javascript/

Comment: Are there JavaScript erros in your console?

Comment: Does the `alert` show up after clicking on login? Also you have two different JS, one in the JS field and one in the HTML `<head>`, which one is the correct one?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on Javascript to validate a form. People with Javascript turned off will be able to enter junk. Vai remando marujo :)

Comment: No errors in my console @AlainVanderbroeck

Comment: @elveti already corrected it

Comment: @AlainVanderbroeck can't get to the site you pointed

Comment: So how do i do it? @statosdotcom

Comment: Server side scripting, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By switching `type='submit'` to `type='button'` I was able to get the redirect working.

When clicking a `submit` button, then opening an `alert`, the browser was waiting for the alert to close to submit the form. So it was submitting the form before the redirect and return false could be processed.

Due to browser restrictions, the redirect doesn't work in snippets but it is actually working.

```js
var attempt = 3; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
if ( username == "teste" && password == "teste"){
alert ("Login successfully");
window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/webhp?ie=UTF-8&rct=j"; // Redirecting to other page.
return false;
}
else{
attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
// Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
if( attempt == 0){
document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
return false;
}
}
}
```

```css
/*******************************************LOGIN********************************/
html, body {
  width: 3779.527559055px;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #444;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 background-color: #111;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}

zoom{
zoom: 25%;
}
/*******************************************SHUTDOWN BUTTON********************************/
#btn1{
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

button img{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
/*********************************************LOGIN***************************************/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide);

::-moz-selection {
    background: #cc0000;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #cc0000;
    text-shadow: none;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}

html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.background-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: default;
  outline: none;
}

form {
  background: #111;
  border-radius: .4em;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  height: 1000px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 1500px;
}

form:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #111111, #444444, #b6b6b8, #444444, #2F2F2F, #272727);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

form:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  left: 34%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  width: 8px;
}

.inset {
  border-top: 1px solid #19191a;
  padding: 20px;
}

form h1 {
  font-family: 'Audiowide';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 200px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

form h1 {
  color: #FFbb00;
  font-family: Audiowide;
  font-weight: normal;
}

form h1.poweron {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  animation: flicker 1s ease-in-out 1 alternate, neon 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
}

form h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 180px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 138px;
  transform-style: flat;
  transform: skew(20deg);

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%, hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0.2)), color-stop(100%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#42ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsla(0,0%,100%,0.1) 0%,hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 100%);

}

input[type=username], input[type=password] {
  background: linear-gradient(#1f2124,#27292c);
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=username]:disabled, input[type=password]:disabled {
 color: #999;
}


.p-container {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.p-container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.p-container span {
  color: #0d93ff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: #fb0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  color: #873C00;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.denied {
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
  background: #EE0000 !important;
}

input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=submit]:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

input[type=text]:hover:not([disabled]), 
input[type=text]:focus, 
input[type=password]:hover:not([disabled]), 
input[type=password]:focus, 
label:hover ~ input[type=text], 
label:hover ~ input[type=password] {
  background: #27292c;
}


@keyframes neon {
  from {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  to {
      text-shadow: 
      0 0 3px #fff,
      0 0 7px  #fff,
      0 0 13px  #fff,
      0 0 17px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 33px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 38px  #B6FF00,
      0 0 48px #B6FF00,
      0 0 63px #B6FF00;
    }
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  2% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  8% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  10% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  20% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  22% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  24% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  28% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  32% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }

  34% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  36% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  42% {
    text-shadow: none;
  }

  100% {
    text-shadow: 
    0 0 2.5px #fff,
    0 0 5px #fff,
    0 0 7.5px #fff,
    0 0 10px #B6FF00,
    0 0 17.5px #B6FF00,
    0 0 20px #B6FF00,
    0 0 25px #B6FF00,
    0 0 37.5px #B6FF00;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Desk+ - Grupo 36</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PF1.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="Locked Screen">
    <div id="Login">
            <div class="background-wrap">
                    <div class="background"></div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <form id="accesspanel">
                    <h1 id="litheader">Desk+</h1>
                    <div class="inset">
                      <p>
                        <input id="username" type="username" size="64" maxLength="64"
                        placeholder=Username(teste)>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password(teste)" required>
                      </p>
                      <div style="text-align: center;">
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-container">
                      <input onclick="validate()" type="button" id="go" value="Login">
                    </p>
                  </form>
    </div>

    <datalist id="users">
        <option value="teste">
      </datalist>

    <div id="Logout">
    <!---<a href="logout.php" id="LogoutAction"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/exit.png"></a>--->
    <button type="submit" id="btn1"><img src= "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/crystalproject/crystal_project_256x256/apps/exit.png"/></button>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```